# Setting the a WebPages Title with PHP and MySql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

So I have a database the program runs fine connects and all except for one thing I am trying to get the "forum_name" defined under my db and set it as my Title. Pretty much if I click on the link where it takes me to that post or forum page it will get whats under forum_name and print it as the Title.

This is db_connect.php

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "","forum") or die("ERROR: With Connecetion");
 ?>
```

And this is the Reset:

```
<?php
session_start();
require"db_connect.php";
//get the page id
if(isset($_GET['id']) &&is_numeric($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}else{
    die("Error! Does not exist!");
}
//check if Valid Id
 $idCheck = $db->query("SELECT * FROM forum_tabl WHERE forum_id = 'id'");
 if($idCheck->num_rows !==0){
     die("error");
 }
 $row = $idCheck->fetch_object();
 $sql = "SELECT post_id, post_title FROM forum_post WHERE forum_id? AND type= 'o'";
 if($query = $db->prepare($sql)){
     $query->bind_params('s', $id);
     $query->bind_result($post_id, $post_title);
     $query->execute();
     $query->store_result();
 }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><?= $row->forum_name?></title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
    <!-- Theres content that will go here -->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<?=` shortcut don't work on some servers. Try `<?php echo $row->forum_name; ?>`

Comment: Nope still doesn't work. @developerwjk I know the shortcut works on my server but ya i get the error Notice: Trying to get property of non-object on title line.

Comment: Is the title supposed to be coming from the first or second query? In the first query you have `id='id'` which is probably not right, since the id is probably supposed to be a number, right?

Comment: and in the second query, you have `forum_id?` with no `=`

Comment: *Trying to get property of non-object on title line.* means `$row` is not an object. Do `var_dump($row);` to debug the issue.

Comment: well its returning null but would it be `forum_id=?` or how? @developerwjk

Comment: See the `WHERE` condition, `...WHERE forum_id = 'id'...`, I believe it should be `...WHERE forum_id = '$id'`. Use prepared statement though.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul you are right thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the Problem is in this line.

```
$idCheck = $db->query("SELECT * FROM forum_tabl WHERE forum_id = 'id'");
```

and You have to replace it as follows.

```
$idCheck = $db->query("SELECT * FROM forum_tabl WHERE forum_id = '$id'");
```

Comment: Thank you but I also had to change the if statement

Comment: Yes. In this case you have to change the if statement                      $idCheck->num_rows ==0  instead of   $idCheck->num_rows !==0

Comment: This should be `WHERE forum_id=?` not this. The `bind_param` call is correct, and can be repeated here to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
require"db_connect.php";
//get the page id
if(isset($_GET['id']) &&is_numeric($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}else{
    die("Error! Does not exist!");
}
//check if Valid Id
 $idCheck = $db->query("SELECT * FROM forum_tabl WHERE forum_id = " . $id);
 if($idCheck->num_rows !==0){
     die("error");
 }
 $row = $idCheck->fetch_object();
 $sql = "SELECT post_id, post_title FROM forum_post WHERE forum_id? AND type= 'o'";
 if($query = $db->prepare($sql)){
     $query->bind_params('s', $id);
     $query->bind_result($post_id, $post_title);
     $query->execute();
     $query->store_result();
 }
?>
```

The " . $id); is what you are looking for to get this to work. You may want to go through and double check everything such as "forum_tabl" and be sure everything is correct if you have not done so already.

Also double check the following, that extra ? may be messing things up as well depending on your database setup.

```
 $sql = "SELECT post_id, post_title FROM forum_post WHERE forum_id? AND type= 'o'";
```

Best of luck!